# Passportjs - getting req.user as `undefined` if `passport.authenticate` is not present in route as middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, passport.js

I am creating a small social networking site. I have one route `/profile/username` which shows user profile with images that he/she uploaded. another user can like images if he/she is authenticated. otherwise, he/she can just see images he/she can't like images

```
router.get("/:username",async (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.user) // undefined
     if(req.user){
        // send images with values like user liked or not
     }else{
       //send only images
      }
})
```

problem is here that I am getting `undefined` as req.user. nodejs interpret undefined as false.
any help guys? I appreciate your inputs. thank you

Comment: Have you implemented the LocalStrategy and called passport.initialize() ?

Comment: yes, I initialized the passport local strategy